# Rank-based Spatial Clustering in Python

Tags: python, software-recommendations, spatial-statistics, clustering, rank

I was wondering if there was any python (or R) packages out there that can do spatial clustering on ranked data?

For each US state I spatially varying value for education rankings. For example, for Virginia the ranking may be 50 compared to a ranked value of 10 for the state of Missouri. These are not categorical (e.g. A vs B) or ratio (e.g. 1.5), but ranked in the sense that a value of 50 for Virginia does not mean that this state is 5 times higher in educational value that Missouri. Its synonymous to ranked outcomes at the end of a marathon (e.g. 1st, 2nd,....places). Most of the stuff I've been finding online relate to the relationship between records across different attribute themes in tabular data (e.g. Gower distance). I'm looking for a spatially clustering method such as Moran's I where the attribute vector being analyzed is an education rank value for each state polygon.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand: do you have spatially variable data with ranks (a map)? The way you put it seems that Virginia has the same level of 50, is it not a spatial cluster already?

Comment: Hi Andrea, sorry about the misleading information. Your interpretation is correct. Education is spatially variable with ranks. I have a polygon shapefile for the US with each state having a educational ranked value.

Comment: So you have 1 value for each state?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: What do you want your final map to represent?

Comment: I'd just like to have a map showing the spatial clustering of polygons based on their ranked values. Such a map could look like the results of a hot spot analysis of spatially co-ocurring highly ranked value states and spatially co-ocurring lowly ranked valued states.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to obtain a raster with colors depending on the rank value? and maybe to reclassify them in a rank range? Say top 10, 20th-30th etc

Comment: Sort of...I'm searching for a metric similar to spatial outlier detection with Moran's I, but instead of working with ratio data, I have one variable with ranked values. So in addition to what you've suggested with respect to reclassifying into a rank range, I'm looking for patterns of how these ordinal values for education vary with space.

Comment: I sort of understand now, but I do not have a direct answer. I think you should make explicit in the question all the info you gave me and that you are looking at spatial autocorrelation, including its meaning, examples or links.